# search location name in google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I tried to search location name in google map activity.here in onsearch method address.getLatitude() and address.getLongitude are not work.its show red text.anyone please solve my error. below my code

```
public void onSearch(View view)
{
    EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
    String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    if(location != null || !location.equals(""))
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(0,0);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: Can you tell the error?

Comment: error means its just show red text

Comment: by hovering over there, you will get the error name.

Comment: are you get something?

Comment: I think you have imported wrong `Address` class. Try this : `import android.location.Address`

Comment: sukriya bisab..I am from Bangladesh near you.however its work fine when I import it.thanks

Comment: glad it helps you. I'm posting it as an answer. please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, you have either imported the wrong Address class or not imported at all. [The class which you are looking](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) for can be imported using following line:

```
import android.location.Address;
```

The above class contains `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` methods. Another package which also contains `Address` class, which I guess, by mistake you imported is following:

[com.google.android.gms.identity.intents](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/identity/intents/Address)